# How can I convert DateTimePicker to date for save to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, date, transactions, datetimepicker, datetime-format

Please, can you tell me how can I convert format `DateTimePicker` to date, because I can't save format `DateTimePicker` to database because the datatype in the database is only `date`.

Scripts:

```
public void addZam(SqlConnection sql, DateTimePicker denNastupu, DateTimePicker denUkonceni)

// Parameters
SqlParameter denNastupuParam = new SqlParameter("@denNastupu", SqlDbType.Date);
SqlParameter denUkonceniParam = new SqlParameter("@denUkonceni", SqlDbType.Date);

// Inicialization
denNastupuParam.Value = denNastupu;
denUkonceniParam.Value = denUkonceni;

// Add to parameters
addZam.Parameters.Add(denNastupuParam);
addZam.Parameters.Add(denUkonceniParam);

// Execute command
addZam.Prepare();
addZam.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Format in DB:

```
datumNastupu date,
datumUkonceni date,
```

Error:

> You can not convert parameter value from the DateTimePicker to DateTime

Can you offer me any opinion how can I fix it? Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
denNastupuParam.Value = denNastupu.Value;
denUkonceniParam.Value = denUkonceni.Value;
```

You want the value returned by your `DateTimePicker` control, not the control itself. If you're only interested in the `Date` part of the `DateTime` (not clear in the question), use `denNastupu.Value.Date`.